# C++ redefinition of log - static vars conflicting with included globals

Tags: c++, static, name-conflict

I'm porting some code from Swift to C++. I was doing the following at the top of every Swift file:

```swift
private let log = os.Logger("Foo")
```

This defines a `log` variable that is local to the file. It's like `static` in C and C++.

If I try a similar thing in C++, in an implementation file (not header):

```cpp
static MyLib::Logger log("Foo");
```

I get this error:

> Redefinition of 'log' as different kind of symbol, previous definition is here:
> /.../usr/include/c++/v1/math.h:977:1: log(_A1 __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return ::log((double)__lcpp_x);}

So it conflicts with the mathematical `log` function. Is there a way to keep my static `log` variable and somehow give it priority to resolve the name conflict error? Or do I just need to rename my log variable?

Comment: Quick hack: Use an [anonymous namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces) instead of `static`. Might be enough for your purposes. `namespace { MyLib::Logger log("Foo"); }`

Comment: Or use the c++ math header. There log is in the namespace std, so there is no conflict.

Comment: Had to test that one to see if it would work, @gerum . [Looks like it doesn't in at least this case.](https://godbolt.org/z/d4sdn6cvo)

Comment: @user4581301 The anonymous namespace gets be past that line, but then when I try to _use_ the `log` later in the file, I get a similar error about an ambiguous reference.

Comment: That's weird about the <cmath> and namespace not helping. I thought that was the whole point of those <cfoo> headers. Huh.

Comment: In other words, not enough for your case. I knew I should have edited in that it won't work if you actually USE `log`. And why wouldn't you use it? That's kind of the <expletive deleted>ing point, isn't it?

Comment: @user4581301 Your comment was still very useful to me. I'm re-learning C++ and didn't know/remember the anon namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are multiple ways to do it depending on your situation but the easiest way seems to be to just rename your log to something like _log or my_log. If not you can create your own namespace and put your log there.

Comment: Note: `_log` in the global namespace [could still be fatal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/4581301).